# TortoiseSVN: How to get the current working copy 'highest' revision?

Tags: tortoisesvn, revision, working-copy

Ok i have a working copy and i want to know its revision
I know about the `Subrevision` tab in the `properties` window of the working copy but it doesn't show the last revision i updated the working copy to.. In the working copy not all the files at the same revision
The way i'm working with the working copy is the following :
- i checkout a working copy of the repository.
- then i do some modifications and commit them.
- i continue working on the same working copy.. I don't checkout a new one.
- if there're some requierd updates i do them.. Continue working.. Commiting.
So i never checkout a new working copy as i have one so i always work-update-commit on it.

So sometimes i need to work somewhere else so i copy the `working copy` folder to another PC where there's no connection with the repository.. I do some work on it.. Take it back to the work PC and commit it.

So sometimes i get confused about the last working copy i committed so i need to check their revisions and work with the higher one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) tool for this.

Comment: Ok it does exactly what i want.. Thanks